# Object follows path but is displaced

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, parent

I want to track the ball to the path but somehow it is displaced. I can't figure out the problem. I tried several things I found on the internet but the ball either do nothing or moves further away.

[image]

The animation works totally fine, but the ball is displaces all the way to the end.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello what does it give if you press Alt G? It will put the ball at the beginning of the curve. If it doesn't work please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: When I was pressing Alt + G the Object was moving even further away  
But I think I found the problem. I was using relations/parenting and "Follow path" in the object constraints properties at the same time. Additional to that the object I wanted to follow the path wasn't in the center of the world when I was activating "Follow the path" (<- this was one of the main problems i think)